# Can an ISP download data using TR-069?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, isp, mikrotik-routeros

I have a router supplied by my ISP which has a [TR-069](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TR-069) feature and my ISP disabled the ability of controlling that TR-069 (toggling it or configuring it)

My issue is that I am on a limited quota connection (200GB monthly quota), and I started feeling that my ISP is adding fake usage to my quota that I actually don't use but they consider it as used... I then monitored my actual usage using a Mikrotik server and found out that my ISP's website says that I used 200GB of my quota although my actual usage was 114GB only.

So let's get back to the TR-069 part, I started thinking about that thing in my router and if my ISP is using it as a method to steal of my quota or no.

So the question in short is: Can an ISP download data using TR-069? or TR-069 can be used for automatic configuration only?

Thanks!

Comment: 200gb down or up and down combined?

Comment: The link you quoted answers your question [High-level operations possible through TR-069](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TR-069#High-level_operations_possible_through_TR-069)

Comment: If your ISP wanted to rip you off, why would they waste their own bandwidth to do it?

Comment: @anonjnr - both combined

Comment: @DavidPostill - Actually I didn't put that link, it seems the question was edited.

Comment: @Spiff - I contacted my ISP about my case several times and they always said that my usage has no problems. About your question, there is a government authority in my country responsible for spectating the ISPs.. and my thought here is that my ISP may want to let my quota to finish faster but in a regular way (as if I really used that usage - through my router's TR069) they do that to prevent that authority and in the same time charge me for additional quota

Comment: If the ISP wants to charge you for more usage they could just fake the statistics, they wouldn't need to actually use your bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

TR-069 is a protocol that used most by ISP to control clients' devices (modem, router) to support them whenever they need. ISP can control all settings on your device (according to what I know) through this protocol. They can upgrade firmware on your device, adjust settings and much more.

I don't know why they would steal your quota, but there is no need to do that.

Comment: They can do that to charge me for additional quota.